# Unable to get Tinymyc editor value in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am working on Nextjs and i am trying to integrate Tinymyc editor, I tried with following code but still not getting editor value, i am getting error "editor is null"

```
1) After use in "handelsubmit" i used "<Editor />" for display/show editor on page , is this correct ?
2) How can i get value of editor ? i tried with following line but not worked for me 
   const content = editor.getContent();
   alert('content is '+ content);
```

I tried with following code

```
<Editor
    onInit={(evt, ed) => {
      editor = ed;
      const content = editor.getContent();
      const data = {
        first: e.target.name.value,
        last: e.target.cat_name.value,
        content: content, // add the content to the data object
      }
    }}
    initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>"
    init={{
      height: 500,
      menubar: false,
      plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
      ],
      toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
      'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
      'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
      'removeformat | help',
      content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
    }}
  /> // Now how can i get content ? ( how to use this further ) ?
```